# how to run airflow cli command for composer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

This command works as it should:

`gcloud composer environments run <COMPOSER_NAME> dags next-execution -- <DAG_ID>`

But when I add any option to airflow command eg: `-n 5`:

`gcloud composer environments run <COMPOSER_NAME> dags next-execution -- -n 5 <DAG_ID>`

It throws error:

```
kubeconfig entry generated for europe-west1-<ID>.
Executing within the following Kubernetes cluster namespace: composer-<ID2>

Error from server (NotFound): pods "airflow-worker-<ID3>" not found

ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.run) kubectl returned non-zero status code.
```

How do I pass `-n 5` to airflow command properly?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With [gcloud beta](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/composer/environments/run), you should be able to use `Airflow` sub commands, example :

```bash
gcloud beta composer environments run myenv trigger_dag -- some_dag --run_id=foo
```

is equivalent to running the following command from a shell inside the my-environment environment:

```bash
airflow trigger_dag some_dag --run_id=foo
```

I don't tested the command but it should look like :

```bash
gcloud beta composer environments run <COMPOSER_NAME> next-execution -- -n 5 -- dag_id

airflow next_execution [-h] [-sd SUBDIR] dag_id
```

Before to launch all your commands, update the `gcloud cli` from you `Shell` session :

```bash
gcloud components update
```

Comment: unfortunately using beta version of gcloud doesn't solve this issue. I tried different formats, but they all throw erorrs: `gcloud beta composer environments run <COMPOSER_NAME> dags next-execution -- -n 5 <DAG_ID>`
`gcloud beta composer environments run <COMPOSER_NAME> dags next-execution -- -n 5 -- <DAG_ID>`
`gcloud beta composer environments run <COMPOSER_NAME> dags next-execution -n 5 -- <DAG_ID>`